# Handsontable Grid - loading and saving data from aspx web page

Tags: c#, .net, handsontable

Is it possible to load and save data to/from a grid using c# code in the back from an aspx page, or does one have to use a web service (or PHP)?  I have tried and failed using JSON.Net to map a very simple structure to code a backend structure

Is it possible to use JQuery (an ajax `GET` I presume) to make a call to a method in the backend code file (.aspx.cs)?  I have tried using code from various posts on this forum, but there is little information on the backend code (c#), and  all seem to refer to web services.  Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the JavaScript code associated:

```
var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
$(document).find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Default.aspx/getJSData",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (res) {
            handsontable.loadData(res.data);
            $console.text('Data loaded');
        },
        error: function () {
            $console.text('Load error');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to do an Ajax call but you don't need to do a web service (you can).  The function you want exposed to the Ajax call put the `[WebMethod]` Attribute on and an use a Script Manager with the EnablePageMethods attribute set to true.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Method to Access:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SomeFunction(string message, string name)
{

}
```

Ajax call using jQuery

```
(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/SomeFunction",
            data: "{message:'Hello World', name: 'Bob'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

Reference: [Using the WebMethod Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - this gives me plenty to work with.  At the moment VS will not recognise the [Webmethod] attribute, so I am doing a bit of research on that...

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, this looks right, but I cant get it to work.  I needed to add `using System.Web.Services;` to the code-behind file in order for VS to recognise the [Webmethod] attribute.  The parameters you show for the `SomeFunction()` method looks incorrect to me  -  I would have thought we were passing in a single serialised string that we will need to de-serialise.  The thing is, I cannot get the code-behind function to fire  -  I have tried just about everything.  I am getting no errors, just nothing.

Comment: ASP.Net is taking care of the de-serializing.  What it is going to do is match up the query string parameters to the functions method call, so you need to make sure they match.  Or I believe you can leave the parameter list blank and look at the request object to get the values (haven't tested this last bit).

Comment: Great,thanks again @Stephen, the posting of data to the server is working now. Now I have been battling (for hours) to get the loading of data from the server to work - please can you assist with the structure of the server side method -  my javascript code will follow: