# Handsontable ASPX Code behind method for LOADING data to grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, handsontable

In a previous post [Handsontable Grid - loading and saving data from aspx web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681661/handsontable-grid-loading-and-saving-data-from-aspx-web-page) I solved the "ajax data transfer to the server for Saving" with help from Stephen B. Burris Jr, for which many thanks.  I have been unable to get the reverse process to work - that is the loading of data from the server to the grid.  I am using sample code from GitHub for the client-side javascript code, but what I am not clear on at all is how the data needs to be "packaged" in response to the ajax call.  I would be very greatful if someone could show me the structure of the code-behind method.  Below is the javascript code with the ajax call:

```
            var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
            $(document).find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/getJSData",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (res) {
                        handsontable.loadData(res.data);
                        $console.text('Data loaded');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $console.text('Load error');
                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061532/loading-handsontable-from-an-ajax-enabled-wcf-service/17355015#17355015)

It is a working solution using WCF.

You haven't stated what technologies it needs to be, but I noticed the C# tag.

I hope it helps.