# Loading Handsontable from an AJAX-enabled WCF Service

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, handsontable

I'm trying to display data in a Handsontable from an AJAX-enabled WCF Service but it does not show anything.

```
CarsService.svc:

    [DataContract]
    public class Car
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CarsService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public IEnumerable<Car> GetCars()
        {
            var cars = new List<Car>();
            var car1 = new Car()
            {
                Name = "Kia",
                Year = "2008"
            };
            var car2 = new Car()
            {
                Name = "Nissan",
                Year = "2009"
            };
            cars.Add(car1);
            cars.Add(car2);
            return cars;
        }
    }

WebPage:

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/Scripts/Handsontable/jquery.handsontable.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/Scripts/Handsontable/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/Scripts/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/jquery.contextMenu.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/Handsontable/jquery.handsontable.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(window).load(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/CarsService.svc/GetCars",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $("#exampleGrid").handsontable("loadData", result);
            })
            .fail(function (r, o) {
                alert("Failed : " + r.responseText);
            });
        });
        </script> 

        <div id="exampleGrid" class="dataTable"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your browser show when you navigate to `http://..../CarsService.svc/GetCars`

Comment: It asks me if I would like to save a file. The file looks like this:{"d":[{"__type":"Car:#GridWebApp","Name":"Kia","Year":"2008"},{"__type":"Car:#GridWebApp","Name":"Nissan","Year":"2009"}]}

Comment: I forgot to add that when I run the application the WCF service is called (Perhaps that's why I got the Stackoverflow error).

Comment: Most probably your Handsontable expects a different json. I would also try adding `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` to `WebGet` attribute but better, refer to documentation of it.

Comment: If I add this:        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
I get an error: The body style 'Bare' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'.

Comment: With this I get the same result as before: [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me:

I use newtonsoft's Json.net:
http://json.codeplex.com/

The contract for the service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
[OperationContract]
string GetAllData();
```

the wcf service returns:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

and the javascript...
('data' is what is returned by my Ajax call)

```
var myData = JSON.parse(data.d);

var config = {
    data: myData,
    columns: [
        //I had to set 'data' of each column
        { data: "OtherParty" },
        { data: "Reference" }
    ]
};

$container.handsontable(config);
```

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

> EncryptionUtils

```
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class EncryptionUtils
{
  private Cipher decryptCipher;
  private BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

  public EncryptionUtils() throws SecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());

    char[] pass = "edurixkey".toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = {
      -93, 33, 36, 44, 
      -14, -46, 62, 25 };

    int iterations = 3;

    init(pass, salt, iterations);
  }

  public void init(char[] pass, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws SecurityException {
    try {
      PBEParameterSpec ps = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
      SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
      SecretKey k = kf.generateSecret(new javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec(pass));

      decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      decryptCipher.init(2, k, ps);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new SecurityException("Could not initialize Encryption: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public synchronized String decrypt(String str) throws SecurityException {
    try {
      byte[] dec = decoder.decodeBuffer(str);
      byte[] utf8 = decryptCipher.doFinal(dec);
      return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new SecurityException("Could not decrypt: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```