# How to bind a datable from ASP.Net to handsontable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am very new to Handsontable and looking to bind a asp.net datatable to Handsontable.
Can anyone please help me with code snippet. I just loaded Handsontable in my page

Here is my code: i am getting an error  **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'example' is undefined**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="example"></div>
    </form>
</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function example(dt) {
            var data = dt;
            $('#example').handsontable({
                data: data,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                colHeaders: false,
                contextMenu: true
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Server side code

```
dt = Load a table here
        Dim data As String = GetJson(dt)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "example", (Convert.ToString("example(") & data) + ");", True)

    Public Function GetJson(dt As DataTable) As String

        Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through a loop with your datatable and generate data object using this table. Then you can render that in your script.

Comment: Sorry dude you have to try that at least once and post your code if is does not work. This place is not to ask others to code for you.

Comment: Thing is i dont find a single example on google to load data from asp.net to Handsontable :(

Comment: https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/issues/686 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681661/handsontable-grid-loading-and-saving-data-from-aspx-web-page

Comment: Thanks i just posted a code and getting an error. Looks like not able to call javascript function from server side